# Bootstrap 3 - Extend and upgrade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, bower

I have installed Bootstrap with Bower in my project

```
bower install bootstrap
```

There are several LESS variables that I'd like to override

```
- less/modals.less (some transition effects)
- less/variables.less (colors)
```

I don't want to change anything on the bower package so it can be upgraded later.

I'd rather not like to have to redefine an entire Gruntfile for my small modifications.

What do you suggest me to be able to build my bootstrap with Grunt taking my variables keeping the ability to upgrade it with Bower later ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `bootstrap.less`. change its `@import` directives with new .less you want. (Gruntfile.js has reference to variables.less, so I think this option is not what you are looking for).


Or extract (or override) variables you changed from files and to separate `.less` file(-s) and add new `@import` to `bootstrap.less` file.

Comment: That's what I'm going try to do. But also, I'll try to find a way to run the Bootstrap Gruntfile from my Gruntfile.